# How can I capture the complete webpage state, including dynamically loaded content from subsequent responses?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm currently working on a project where I need to programmatically capture the complete state of a webpage, including any dynamically loaded content from subsequent responses. Currently, I'm using the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to get the initial [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) response from the webpage, but it seems to lack the full DOM that includes modifications from additional requests made by the webpage.

One challenge I'm facing is that I cannot make those additional requests directly, because the response I receive from my initial request doesn't include the filters used in the subsequent [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) requests made by the webpage.

Given that the browser, with only the input of the URL, can generate the complete page state, is there's a tool or library that can provide a similar result? I'm looking for a way to capture the entire page state, including the effects of subsequent responses.

What tools, libraries, or approaches can be recommended that could help achieve this?

I attempted to inspect the page elements and find POST request filters inside, but it failed.

Comment: requests is not the tool to use for things like this. Either Selenium or Playwright or similar framework that can actually run javascript and modify the existing DOM is what you need..